# Pass data between 2 dynamically loaded User control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a scenario where I dynamically load 2 user controls in a webform, and need them to interact together. Here's the code :

```
default.aspx.cs
ControlA cA = (ControlA)LoadControl("~/controlA.ascx");
ControlB cB = (ControlB)LoadControl("~/controlB.ascx");
Page.Controls.Add(cA);
Page.Controls.Add(cB);
```

Now the thing is, controlB needs to pass a data to controlA. Data is not from an event (well part of). When user click on a link from controlB, we get data from a DB, and what I need to pass to controlA is the ID of the first data fetch from request. And of course, when user click on the link in controlB, page do a postback.

I looked at events & delegates, but I can't make it to work. Is it the right way to go ?

If anyone could have a clue, it would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty method that comes to mind is to declare that ID of the first data fetch as a public property of ControlB, and set that value on your link postback's handler on controlB
Eg. 
On ControlB's event handler :

```
public void Link_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 this.FirstFetchedId = GetValueFromDB();
}
```

Then on ControlA's PreRender :

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
ControlB cB = this.Page.FindControl("ControlBId") as ControlB; // either by ID or loop trough controls to find it by type
var YourIdIsHere = cB.FirstFetchedId;
base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```